# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.ensemble.gradient_boosting'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, joblib

When I'm trying to run below command:

```
# load pretrained model as clf
clf = joblib.load("./model_data/boston_housing_prediction.joblib")
```

I receive this error after calling joblib.load:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.ensemble.gradient_boosting'
```

The imports I used:

```
joblib==1.3.1
scikit-learn==1.3.0
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you have a newer version of `sklearn`. The import is now `sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier`

In previous versions, the import was indeed `sklearn.ensemble.gradient_boosting`.

---

You need to downgrade your versions. E.g [v0.14](https://scikit-learn.org/1.2/whats_new/v0.14.html). Use this if you want to force the downfrade:

```
pip install -U scikit-learn==0.14
```

Comment: I executed command:
pip install --user -U scikit-learn==0.14
,But I received below error:
        File "<string>", line 156, in <module>
        File "<string>", line 148, in setup_package
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

Comment: can you try `pip install -U scikit-learn==0.14`